# How to display duplicates between 2 repositories

Tags: debian, packaging

I got 2 repos locally. One is a copy of Squeeze and another is a custom one, and is managed by reprepro. Are there ready-made tools that would generate a list of duplicate packages between the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me, I've been seating on a script that makes this far faster and easier:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os
import gzip
import apt_pkg

repo1 = "~/.repo_local/dists/cache/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz"
repo1 = os.path.expanduser(repo1)
repo1 = apt_pkg.TagFile(gzip.open(repo1, "rb"))
repo1 = dict([(pkg["Package"], pkg["Version"]) for pkg in repo1])

repo2 = "~/.repo_bin/dists/squeeze/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz"
repo2 = os.path.expanduser(repo2)
repo2 = apt_pkg.TagFile(gzip.open(repo2, "rb"))
repo2 = dict([(pkg["Package"], pkg["Version"]) for pkg in repo2])

apt_pkg.init_system()
found = False

for pkg in repo1:
    if pkg in repo2:
        vc = apt_pkg.version_compare(repo1[pkg], repo2[pkg])
        if vc == 0:
            print("{:<30}{:<30}({})".format(repo1[pkg], repo2[pkg], pkg))
            found = True

if found:
    print("=" * 90)
    print("{:<30}{:<30}({})".format("custom", "official", "package name"))
else:
    print("nothing matching search criteria found")
```

Comment: `apt_pkg` is from **python3-apt**.

Answer (score 4):

You could go along with [fdupes](http://netdial.caribe.net/~adrian2/fdupes.html) which uses md5sum to compare files and allows deletion of duplicates. I don't know enough about Debian repositories though, so you'll probably have to drop those files from some package registry as well (I think there is a file called packages.gz or similar in each repository).

So what you should do:

1. Use fdupes to generate a list of duplicates
2. use that list to drop packages from the repository information
3. delete the actual files

Comment: Thanks for that. Very useful stuff. Once used it and forgot about it. BTW repoupdate has a command that deletes the package: it will remove both the repo info of that package (packages.gz) and the actual file itself.